# ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed when USB unplugged

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, objectdisposedexception

I have a device (USB->serial) and an application software (.NET 3.5) connected to the device COM port. There is a function which is able to reboot the device (done by sending a serial command to the device).

The problem is, `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown by `System.dll` when the device is rebooted. (randomly thrown & uncatchable even though I have wrapped the code inside try-and-catch block).

I have found some information online that this exception is due to SerialPort's internal Stream object getting disposed by the garbage collector when the physical port disappears.

I have implemented the coding 
i.e. `GC.SuppressFinalize(SerialPort)` and 
 `GC.SuppressFinalize(SerialPort.BaseStream)` in connect function,
and also `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize` in disconnect function
as suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a1825d2-c84b-4620-91e7-3934a4d47330/c-serialport-systemobjectdisposedexception-safe-handle-has-been-closed-in-systemdll?forum=netfxbcl)
But it does not help to solve the ObjectDisposedException when USB is unplugged and removed from device manager.

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: `Any suggestion to solve this issue?` Are you able to show us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Serial ports are not plug-and-play devices so cannot know that the USB device driver suffered a heart attack and they are holding on to a junk handle.  Same kind of problem as jerking the connector while the port is being used.  And the primary reason that the "Safely remove hardware" tray icon exists.  You **must** interlock this in your code/ui and Close() the serial port before you do this.

Comment: Hi mjwills, The issue randomly occurs when I connect to the device COM port and physically unplug the USB cable. I only got the issue once so far in my own Windows 8 PC, but my teammate got the issue more frequent than me in his Windows 10 PC.

Hi Hans Passant, do you mean that I need to manually disconnect from the serial port BEFORE physically unplug the USB cable? I have implemented disconnect the serial port when USB is removed.